# rendering <IPython.core.display.HTML object> in Visual Studio Code - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to see/render an HTML object in VS code? When I run my Python render function, I get this as a result in the console:

<IPython.core.display.HTML object>

or am I forced to run it in a Juypter notebook to see the HTML object?

Answer (score -1):

You can also try the `displacy.serve`.

Such as:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep")
```

Then browse it through `http://localhost:5000/`.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers).